# Volume of a pyramid as a determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have three given points, A, B and C, each of them is a corner of a pyramid. Another corner is located in origo.

The task is to set up a determinant to describe the pyramids volume.

Unfortunately, my book and Wikipedia won´t agree on how to do this, that´s why I´m asking you guys.

PS. The follow up question is if the volume would be any different if the position vectors (**a**, **b** and **c**) and origo all where located in the same plane?

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: How do your book and wikipedia disagree?

Comment: If you have only the four _corners_ of a pyramid, then how do you know how _tall_ it is? It looks like you don't have enough information to locate the apex.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Well, it's probably a tetrahedron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parallelepiped spanned by $\mathbf a, \mathbf b, \mathbf c$ has (oriented) volume $(\mathbf a\times \mathbf b)\cdot \mathbf c$ (or with any permutation thereof). The pyramid has $\frac16$ of this volume. The expression can also be written as 
$$V = \frac16 \det(\mathbf a, \mathbf b, \mathbf c)$$
i.e. one sixth of the determinant of the matrix made from the three given vectors. If all vertoces of the pyramid are coplanar, the volume is obviously 0 (and that is also what the determinant gives).

Comment: Ahh, great explanation, thank you. Does it matter if**a**, **b** and **c** are rows or columns in the determinant? Because it´s always rows in matrices, so this confused me.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. The determinant of the transpose of a matrix is the same as the determinant of the original matrix.

Comment: Ahh, ok, thank you for taking your time. Appreciate it.