# Trigonometry - Calculating the pyramid volume

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem:

> There be the points $P_0(0,0,0)$, $P_1(1,1,1)$, $P_2(2,-1,2)$ and $P_3(3,0,1)$. Calculate the volume of the pyramid.

Now I assumed the base of the pyramid is a triangle, with points $P_1$, $P_2$ and $P_3$.

So I know $\underline u:=\overrightarrow{P_1P_2} = <1, -2, 1>$ and $\underline v:=\overrightarrow{P_1P_3}=<2,-1,0>$.

I calculated the angle between $\underline u$ and $\underline v$:

$$\cos\theta:=\frac{\underline{u}\cdot\underline{v}}{||\underline{u}||\,||\underline{v}||}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{30}}\Longrightarrow \theta=43.0887^\circ$$
$$S_\Delta=\frac{||\underline{u}||\,||\underline{v}||\sin\theta}{2}=1.87$$

and I thought the pyramid's height to be $\,2\,$ , so the volume is $\,\,\displaystyle{V=\frac{S_\Delta\cdot 2}{3}=1.246}$

I believe I'm somewhat wrong with this.

Help will be much appreciated!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202407/volume-of-a-pyramid-as-a-determinant

Comment: For the record, I suggested an edit improving the title, removing a tag, and adding two tags, but [it was rejected](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2003887).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is relatively simple because one of your points is at the origin.  The volume of your pyramid is then equal to $1/6$ of the determinant of the matrix formed by the other points:

$$V = \frac{1}{6} \left |\begin{array}\\1&1&1\\2&-1&2\\3&0&1 \end{array} \right |$$

Evaluating the determinant, I get $V=1$.